# RSA algorthum calculations

Tags: cryptography, rsa, public-key

I have been working though a network book and hit the RSA section.
Consider the RSA algorithm with p=5 and q=11.

```
so I get N = p*q = 55 right?

and z = (p-1) * (q -1) = 40
```

I think I got this right but the book is not very clear on how to calculate this.

The example in the book says that e = 3 but does not give a reason why. Because the author likes it or is there another reason?

and how do i go about finding d so that de= 1(mod z) and d < 160

Thanks for any help with this its a bit above me right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your calculations of *n* and *z* are correct.

An RSA cryptosystem consists of three variables *n*, *d* and *e*. Variable *e* is the least important of the three, and is usually chosen arbitrarily to make computations simple; 3 and 65537 are the most common choices for *e*. The only requirements are that *e* is odd and co-prime to the totient (*z* in your implementation); thus *e* is frequently chosen prime so that it will be co-prime to the totient no matter what totient is chosen. The reason that 3 and 65537 are frequently used for *e* is because it makes the computation easy; both numbers have only two 1-bits in their binary representation, so only two iterations of a complicated loop are needed.

You can see an implementation of an RSA cryptosystem at [my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com/2010/11/16/rsa-cryptography/). If you poke around there, you will also find some other crypto-related stuff that may interest you.

Comment: The totient (p-1)(q-1) is not necessarily co-prime to e: e may divide it. *If* p and q are chosen to have special properties, e.g. p - 1 = 2p' then your statement may be true.

Answer (score 2):

what you are looking for is the [extended euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm)

for an example see wikipedia or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422223/encryption-rsa-algorithm/6449214#6449214)